Как преобразовать ассемблерных код в объектный файл
Начнём с того что на эту тему есть вопрос, который был задан в сентябре прошлого года. Ответа я в этом вопросе не нашёл. Да я читал комментарии. Всё что я из них понял, так это то, что мне надо идти в ВУЗ(а я школу только заканчиваю).
Насчёт таблицы машинного кода я знаю. Но если посмотреть объектные файлы (через команду nm в Linux и dumpbin в Windows) то мы увидим некую структуру по которой расположены эти коды. Если я просто переведу весь ассемблерных код в эти команды, то такой структуры не будет.
Вопрос заключается в том, как добиться такой структуры, которая находится в объектном файле.
Ещё есть вопрос: может в объектном файле не машинный код, а микро код?

Ну да, у объектного файла, так же как у виндовых com и особенно exe файлов есть своя структура, про неё вам и нужно читать. Точка входа, информационный блок и т.п. Какая-то часть файла будет соответствовать вашему ассемблерному коду, но не вся.

А где, CrazyElf,  про эту структуру можно прочитать

Для Windows исторически два формата объектных файлов: COFF, OMF. Про COFF можно почитать например здесь: https://wiki.osdev.org/COFF, а также в документации от microsoft. Есть модификация этого формата MS COFF. Компиляторы Borland/Embarcadero выдают объектные файлы другого формата - OMF. Под Linux используется формат ELF для и для объектных файлов, и для исполняемых файлов, и для динамических библиотек.

COFF частично похож на Portable Executable (формат exe и dll), многие структуры одни и те же.

(откуда я это знаю - где-то десяток лет назад интересовался, как написать свой линкер, но в итоге забил)

Спасибо, insolor

insolor, раз вы интересовались как написать свой компоновщик, может нам стоит поговорить?

Понятие "объектный файл" весьма расплывчатое. Разные компиляторы в разное время с разными настройками сваливают в таких файлах очень разное содержимое, а не обязательно машинный код. Если хотите примера, то можно посмотреть на исходный код nasm https://github.com/netwide-assembler/nasm/blob/master/output/outobj.c

@МатвейЖуковский нет, не стоит, меня давно не интересует эта тема, возвращаться к ней я не собираюсь. Ключевые слова для поиска я вам дал, дальше самостоятельно.

Ладно, insolor, но все равно вам огромное спасибо

Почему не подходит ассемблер (программа) для этих целей? Если пишете свой компоновщик поищите open-source на github ознакомьтесь с кодом

Чем, @RedFox? Вопрос заключается не как пользоваться ассемблером на Linux, а как создать свой ассемблер.

Виноват, не так понял вопрос

Возможно, ответ на Ваш вопрос был дан в enSO: How Do You Make An Assembler?
Раз Вас интересует этап ассемблирования и создания объектного файла, то четвертая и пятая ссылки англоязычной статьи ведут на спецификации объектных файлов. С ними придётся ознакомиться, так как объектные файлы содержат в себе не просто перевод ассемблерных команд в машинный код, но и другие метаданные, в том числе информацию об отладке, информацию о компоновке динамически подключаемых библиотек и сведения о том, как операционная система должна загружать различные разделы файла в память. Следовательно, совпасть простой перевод ассемблерного кода в машинные коды с реальным объектным файлом не может.
Первая ссылка ответа ведет на книгу про создание ассемблера - файл. Её же рекомендовали в схожем обсуждении. Можете посмотреть первую главу, в которой объясняются варианты разных ассемблеров, схемы их работы, а также построение объектных файлов.
Также существует проект The Assembler Developer's Kit - сайт с мануалами по созданию своего ассемблера. Возможно он будет более прикладным, чем книга выше.
На русском языке информации именно по созданию ассемблеров, а не программировании на языке ассемблера, не то чтобы много, но есть обзорная статья, по которой хотя бы можно понять процессы компиляции.

Чтобы преобразовать ассемблерный код, используется nasm. Это такая утилита, позволяющая собрать код на ассемблере в объектный файл.
Например:
Файл Programm.asm, который надо преобразовать в файл:
section .data
    msg db 'Hello, World!', 0

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    ; write our string to stdout
    mov eax, 4          ; syscall number for sys_write
    mov ebx, 1          ; file descriptor 1 is stdout
    mov ecx, msg        ; pointer to our message
    mov edx, 13         ; length of our message
    int 0x80            ; call the kernel

    ; exit
    mov eax, 1          ; syscall number for sys_exit
    xor ebx, ebx        ; exit code 0
    int 0x80            ; call the kernel

И команда, которая выполнит "превращение" Programm.asm в Programm.o:
nasm -f elf64 program.asm -o program.o

Готово!!!

Я про это знаю. Мне надо создать что-то на подобие nasm
